# Recursive load in c#, what am I missing?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am reading a .json file that contains tile information.  Each tile could have multiple child tiles and those could have child tiles and so on.  I'm successfully reading this file.  The problem comes in when I try to recursively read this file into my own class structure.  The class structure is here...

```
public class GameObjectModel
    {
        public Tuple<float, float> center { get; set; } new Tuple<float, float>(0, 0);
        public SizeF size { get; set; }= new SizeF(0, 0);
        public string fullPath { get; set; }
        public List<GameObject> modelGameObjects { get; set; } = new List<GameObject>();
    }

    public class GameObjectModelTree
    {
        public GameObjectModel model { get; set; } = new GameObjectModel();
        public List<GameObjectModelTree> children { get; set; } = new List<GameObjectModelTree>();
    }
```

Now, I have a function that recursively populates the above model, the problem is the last data I use to populate this model becomes the model for everything in the tree.  So, I stripped it out to the simplest code I could and I'm still having a problem.

```
private GameObjectModelTree ExecuteRegularLoad(Ogc3dTile.Tile tileRoot, string path, bool baseSizeSet)
{
    GameObjectModelTree modelTree = new GameObjectModelTree();
    GameObjectModelTree tTree = new GameObjectModelTree();
    List<GameObjectModelTree> childTree = new List<GameObjectModelTree>();
    List<Ogc3dTile.Tile> loadTiles = new List<Ogc3dTile.Tile> ();

    GameObjectModel singleModel = LoadSingleModel(tileRoot, path, baseSizeSet);
    modelTree.model = singleModel;

    loadTiles = tileRoot.children;
    for (int i = 0; i < loadTiles.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObjectModel childModel = LoadSingleModel(loadTiles[i], path, baseSizeSet);
        tTree.model = childModel;
        childTree.Add(tTree);
        loadTiles.AddRange(loadTiles[i].children);
    }
    modelTree.children = childTree;
    return modelTree;
}
```

Inside the for loop, when I print out the information for modelTree.model it is the exact information as childModel even though I'm not assigning it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the code for `Ogc3dTile.Tile`?

Comment: You always add the same `tTree` object instance to the `childTree` list. And you simply replace the `model` property of this instance at `tTree.model = childModel`. `tTree` should be created in the `for` loop.

Comment: It turns out that this is a misunderstanding on my part on how pass by reference and pass by value works in c#.  My LoadSingleModel() method alters the fullPath parameter of the GameObjectModel class.  It turns out that it's changing it for every instance of GameObjectModel that I have.  My guess is that's because I have public get; set; in my parameter delcarations.  I think I should try private set and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @GWimpassinger I posted the flattened tree problem as a separate ticket.  If you have ideas on it, it's located here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254989/build-nested-model-of-nested-list-using-recursion-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with referencing object instances in your code. Because of that, you change object instances, which I think, you don't intend to change.

*Variables*, *parameters*, *fields* and *properties* of a `class` type always store *references* to object instances of this class or a subtype of this class. Those don't store the object instance, only the reference! If you have multiple variables referencing the *same* object instance you can manipulate/change this object instance via any of them.

Let's see a very simple example. Consider the following class:

```
public class Simple { public int field; }
```

And the code using this class:

```
private static void TestSimple()
{
    Simple a = new Simple();
    Simple b = a; // b references the same object instance
                  // a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()

    a.field = 2; // a.field == 2 AND b.field == 2
    b.field = 3; // a.field == 3 AND b.field == 3 

    b = new Simple(); // b references a new object; a still references the other/old one
                      // a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode()
    b.field = 4; // a.field == 3 AND b.field == 4
}
```

After `Simple b = a` `b` references the **same** object instance as `a`. There is only **one** object, and both variables reference it. Therefore all changes to the instance via `b` are seen on `a`. And everything done via `a` is seen on `b`.

After the line `b = new Simple()` `b` references a new separate object instance.

Now let's have a look at your code. I added some comments to highlight the *things you may have missed*.

```
private GameObjectModelTree ExecuteRegularLoad(Ogc3dTile.Tile tileRoot, string path, bool baseSizeSet)
{
    GameObjectModelTree modelTree = new GameObjectModelTree(); 

    // (1) create another GameObjectModelTree
    GameObjectModelTree tTree = new GameObjectModelTree(); 

    List<GameObjectModelTree> childTree = new List<GameObjectModelTree>();

    // (2) create a List<> of Tile
    List<Ogc3dTile.Tile> loadTiles = new List<Ogc3dTile.Tile> ();


    GameObjectModel singleModel = LoadSingleModel(tileRoot, path, baseSizeSet);
    modelTree.model = singleModel;

    // now the reference to List<> of Tile created in (2) is dismissed and
    // replaced by the reference to the tileRoot.children object instance
    // any changes to loadTiles is also a change in tileRoot.children        
    loadTiles = tileRoot.children;

    for (int i = 0; i < loadTiles.Count; i++)
    {
        // get a new object instance and store the reference to childModel
        GameObjectModel childModel = LoadSingleModel(loadTiles[i], path, baseSizeSet);

        // in every iteration the same tTree object instance, created in (1)
        // is used and therefore we always update the model property
        // of this instance. The reference to the GameObjectModel from the 
        // last iteration is now dismissed. The garbage collector will eventually
        // free object instances from the previous iterations.
        tTree.model = childModel;

        // always add the object instance created in (1)
        // after the nth call to childTree.Add(tTree) the list
        // contains nth times the *same* object instance.
        childTree.Add(tTree);

        loadTiles.AddRange(loadTiles[i].children);
    }

    modelTree.children = childTree;
    return modelTree;
}
```

Here is a revised method, where I address the problems I have found so far and try to solve your *last model loaded, becomes the model for everyting in the tree* problem.

```
private static GameObjectModelTree ExecuteRegularLoad2(Ogc3dTile.Tile tileRoot, string path, bool baseSizeSet)
{
    GameObjectModelTree modelTree = new GameObjectModelTree();
    List<Ogc3dTile.Tile> loadTiles = new List<Ogc3dTile.Tile> ();

    GameObjectModel singleModel = LoadSingleModel(tileRoot, path, baseSizeSet);
    modelTree.model = singleModel;

    loadTiles.AddRange(tileRoot.children);
    for (int i = 0; i < loadTiles.Count; i++)
    {
        GameObjectModel childModel = LoadSingleModel(loadTiles[i], path, baseSizeSet);
        var newTree = new GameObjectModelTree() { model = childModel }; // using object initializer syntax
        modelTree.children.Add(newTree);
        loadTiles.AddRange(loadTiles[i].children);
    }

    return modelTree;
}
```

There are two things which I don't address right now. You mentioned a problem in the `LoadSingleModel` in a comment. Without the code, we can't help. The second thing is, that your algorithm flatten the tree in `tileRoot` down to two levels, the root element and anything else becomes a direct child of this root. All newly loaded `childModel`s are added directly to the `childTree` list which is at the end simply assigned to `modelTree.children` in your code.

If `tileRoot` looks something like this:

- Root

  - Child1

    - Child 1A
    - Child 1B
    - Child 1C

      - Child 1Ca
      - Child 1Cb
  - Child2

    - Child 2A

      - Child 2Aa
    - Child 2B
  - Child 3

`modelTree` will become this

- Root

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
  - Child 3
  - Child 1A
  - Child 1B
  - Child 1C
  - Child 2A
  - Child 2B
  - Child 1Ca
  - Child 1Cb
  - Child 2Aa